# Installing xCode on Mac 10.7.2 - I need to know the version of xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I need to download and install `xcode`. But i need to know the version of `xCode` that i need to install on a `Mac 10.7.2`. Event the [link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#) says that i am capable of installing `xcode` `4.3.2`, i herd that it crashes.

So what is the stable version of `xcode` that i could install on `10.7.2` ?

Comment: Why is it that i should have to upgrade it ?

Comment: Some people will say that every version crashes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4.3 is required for building on iOS devices running 5.1. Xcode 4.3 appears to be very stable, I have not had any issues with it whatsoever. Just search for "Xcode" in the Mac App Store, and you can download it from there.

Comment: When i try to download it, it says that i should upgrade my OS to 10.7.3. So i was looking for a stable version that will work for OS 10.7.2

Comment: @Illep In the iOS Dev Center, you can download either Xcode version 4.3.1 or version 4.2. In my opinion, version 4.3.1 and 4.2 are both very stable on Mac 10.7.2.

Comment: My installation of OS X 10.7.2 doesn't allow me to install Xcode 4.3 or 4.3.1, only 4.2.1 and down. How did you guys do it?

Answer (score 2):

Xcode is available in app store, you don't have to go to iOS dev center to download it.

Comment: Also, even if you go to the iOS Dev Center, you will be redirected to the OSX App Store.

Comment: Yeah but you can only download the latest version of Xcode from the app store, which won't run on 10.7.2.